# AWS aurora Postgresql minor version upgrade with Global cluster failing with terraform

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, upgrade, terraform-provider-aws

I have a global cluster with primary cluster in us-east and secondary cluster in us-west deployed using terraform module in terraform registry.
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds-aurora

Now , when i try to upgrade from 11.7 to 11.9 getting below error.

## Error:

Failed to update engine_version on global cluster member (arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:ACCOUNTXXXXXXX:cluster:prod-test-aurora): InvalidParameterValue: Invalid database cluster identifier:  arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:ACCOUNTXXXXXXX:cluster:prod-test-aurora.

======
Found few references in github with same error but not find the solutions.
My code is same as in below link as well.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21879

Please advise, how to upgrade minor version with global cluster enabled using Terraform.